# add multiple selected dates of calendar in mail body wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, email

In MyCalendar_SelectedDatesChanged() event i am showing all multiple selected dates in list box. I need to pick all these dates and add in email body line by line.
sending mail code :

```
login = new NetworkCredential("wapsatest@gmail.com", "wapsatest123456");
                    client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                    client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(587);
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.Credentials = login;
                    msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress("wapsatest" + "smtp.gmail.com".Replace("smtp.", "@"), "nWorks Employee", Encoding.UTF8) };
                    msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("saurabh.pawar@nworks.co"));
                    msg.Subject = "Requested for leave by "+comboboxEmployee.Text;
                    msg.Body = "///////////////List of dates coming from list box name selecteddates";
 msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                    msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                    client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
                    string userstate = "sending.......";
                    client.SendAsync(msg, userstate);
```

how can i add required body using html format in c# wpf...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code that may help you.

```
login = new NetworkCredential("wapsatest@gmail.com", "wapsatest123456");
client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(587);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = login;
msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress("wapsatest" + "smtp.gmail.com".Replace("smtp.", "@"), "nWorks Employee", Encoding.UTF8) };
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("saurabh.pawar@nworks.co"));
msg.Subject = "Requested for leave by "+comboboxEmployee.Text;

//-------------------Code for your Email body---------------------
string strBody = string.Empty;
int i = 1;
strBody += "///////////////List of dates coming from list box name selecteddates";
strBody += Environment.NewLine;
foreach (var item in lstDate)  // here "lstDate" is name of your list where you store all date.
{
    //strBody += item.ToShortDateString() + Environment.NewLine;
    strBody += "Some text before date".
    strBody += i + ". " + item.ToShortDateString() + " (" + item.DayOfWeek + ")";
    strBody += "Some text after date".
    strBody += "<br/>";
    i++;
}
msg.Body = strBody;
//----------------------------- Over -----------------------------

msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
string userstate = "sending.......";
client.SendAsync(msg, userstate);
```

Comment: Thanks Darshan Bhau... But dates are coming in sequence... I need every date in new line because i need to add some text before and after the dates. Environment.NewLine is not working.

Comment: you can use <br/> instead of Environment.NewLine

Comment: Can I add that date with day(ex.Sunday)

Comment: ya you can add that days with day.

Comment: Thanks. Its Very short and simple solution.

Comment: for the same solution if foreach loop i assigned integer variable i=0 and want to increment it by one for every date to numbering the dates. Is it possible? if yes. How? i used like foreach (DateTime item in MyCalendar.SelectedDates)  // here "lstDate" is name of your list where you store all date.
                                {
                                    int i = 1;
                                    strBody += i+". " + item.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") + ", " + item.DayOfWeek+ "<br/>";
                                    i++;
                                }

Comment: you wan to print serial number in each line am I right ?

Comment: please refer my new updated answer and please vote up if you satisfied with answer.

Comment: you need to initialize int i outside of foreach loop

Comment: Hi... I am trying to add dynamically buttons in html body using c# (for Above code ) but buttons are not appearing. I created object for button and set these values like height,width,content...etc Can you please suggest me any solution?

Comment: As user sets leaves from wpf app... the mail will go to concern person with details of leaves like no of dates and all. now i need to add two buttons say " accept " and " reject " for the response of mail. so that again i need to send mail back to user whether leaves are accepted or not. on the action of button.

Comment: you can simply add two button using html format but it can not fire click event

Comment: Thats why I was trying to create dynamic button but its not appearing in mail body.

Comment: ya exactly mail body is accept only html tags and text not c# controls.

Comment: your requirement is not possible with your architecture you need to change your architecture

Comment: can we add javascript file to response to click event of html button in project.

Comment: ya you can but javascript does not understand your mail sending functionality because your mail sending functionality contains some dll library and it is not possible to add that library into javascript

Comment: Button button = new Button();   
          button.Left = left;
          button.Top = top;
          this.Controls.Add(button);    //this last line is not supporting to me. I thing this is the reason I am not able to add button over there. controls could not be found error.